# apache cordova android guide

Tags: apache, cordova

Has anyone managed to follow the Apache Cordova guide successfully?

Having followed the guide as best I could I ended up with errors:

On the emulator its self on screen: "There was a network error. (file///android_asset/www/index.html)"

In the console of eclipse:

1. error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
2. ERROR: pugin.xml is missing. Add res/xml/plugins.xml to your proj
3. https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/res/xml/pluggins.xml

Has anyone else had any troubles similar to this? I'm hoping i've made some really obvious error but being completely new to this I can't see it with my beginners eye

Answer (score 2):

Many folks have followed the instructions and gotten the app to run. It really sounds like you are missing res/xml/plugins.xml. Did you copy the xml directory from the PhoneGap distribution to your res directory in Eclipse?

Comment: Thank you Simon, i had forgotten to copy the xml folder :)
this worked for me